# Change a driver's source code and compile

Tags: compiling, freebsd, drivers

I have made some little change to `if_igb` in `/usr/src/sys/dev/e1000/if_igb.c`. How can I compile only this file and load it to kernel dynamically?
I'm using FreeBSD 8.2 Release.

Comment: http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/kernelconfig-building.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build just the igb module you can build it from /usr/src/sys/modules/igb.
Note: igb is part of the GENERIC kernel. To use the module remove igb from the kernel config and rebuild your kernel

Comment: Thanks, I tried to add my custom driver to kernel and build it but it says that "config: Error: device "gbeth" is unknown". How can I add my custom driver to kernel?